# Default case of select statement keeps executing

Tags: loops, go

Similar: [golang: goroute with select doesn't stop unless I added a fmt.Print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615955/golang-goroute-with-select-doesnt-stop-unless-i-added-a-fmt-print)

I am writing a code in go, where a goroutine keeps receiving and processing requests on a socket. To stop the execution of current goroutine, I send `true` to a channel from some other goroutine, for which the current goroutine keeps listening in `select` statement.

But the problem here is that even after sending signal on channel, `default` block keeps executing forever. And `case` block is never executed. Following is the code snippet I am having problem with.

```
for {
        select{
            //goroutine should return when something is received on channel 's.stopInbox'
            case <-s.stopInbox:
                fmt.Println("stopInbox")
                return

            //keep receiving and processing requests until anything is received on channel 's.stopInbox'
            default:
                fmt.Println("default case")
                msg, err := responder.Recv(0)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error receiving message", err.Error())
                    break
                }
                envelope := msgToEnvelope(msg)
                s.inbox <- &envelope
            }
        }
```

I have searched for the problem and found solutions as

> With a default statement select will run the default statement every time there is nothing to read from the channels. And because of this, scheduler will never get a chance to schedule another goroutine. Putting the `fmt.Print` statement in is allowing the scheduler to schedule other goroutines.

As per suggestion, I tried putting a print statement in default case, also I tried putting a sleep statement in default case. But nothing is working.

Is there any way to make this work? Also is it possible to achieve the intended by completely avoiding `select` statement?

Comment: Could you post a runnable example on the playground?

Comment: @sk4x0r I don't see a problem with your general structure. Can you post the relevant sections when sending to the `stopInbox`? I also prepared a [running example of what you want](http://play.golang.org/p/o7fu_GGBjw) and it works just fine.

Comment: The code is part of some library I am building. I will upload the code on github and paste the link here.

Comment: I have uploaded the code here: https://github.com/sk4x0r/gocluster
@nemo I also tried a couple of such examples, where the code works as expected. But I don't know what is happening here.
Is there any way to achieve this which will completely avoid use of `select` statement?

Comment: You're not very good at posting self-contained examples reproducing the behaviour you're experiencing. While the complete code is a step in the right direction, you can't expect anyone here to debug your project :) Please try again by posting a self-contained example reproducing your problem on play.

Comment: @nemo Initially I tried to reproduce the problem by creating some smaller example. But the problem in smaller example gets rectified after adding either a print statement or a wait statement in default block. But the same was not being achieved in the actual code I was writing. That's why I put here the code snipplet from original code. Of course, I can't expect somebody else to debug my code for me. I was just wondering if there is some other way, or workaround to achieve returning from a goroutine on receiving a signal on channel.

Comment: Wait, is the code stuck in responder.Recv or looping constantly?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer The code keeps looping and executes `default` case every time.

Comment: Please check that `s.stopInbox` is a valid channel and no other goroutine read from it. If it is a `nil` channel, receive from it never succeed (however, sending to closed channel result in panic) or some other goroutine intercept stopmessage.

Comment: @mechmind I think the problem is with behavior of `default` statement. If I remove `default` statement, the code works properly.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer you were right. The code was stuck in responder.Recv. Setting a timeout on `responder` solved the problem. If someone writes the answer, I can mark it as accepted.  I feel so dumb right now.

Comment: @sk4x0r will do :) I man has to earn his karma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `responder.Recv` without a timeout, your code will block there forever and you won't get to the `default` part. So I guess try setting a timeout ;)