# Golang: goroutine infinite-loop

Tags: go, infinite-loop

When an `fmt.Print()` line is removed from the code below, code runs infinitely. Why?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "sync/atomic"

func main() {
        var ops uint64 = 0 
        for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
                go func() {
                        for {
                                atomic.AddUint64(&ops, 1)
                                fmt.Print()
                        }
                }()
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        opsFinal := atomic.LoadUint64(&ops)
        fmt.Println("ops:", opsFinal)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Go By Example article includes](https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters):

```
   // Allow other goroutines to proceed.
   runtime.Gosched()
```

The `fmt.Print()` plays a similar role, and allows the `main()` to have a chance to proceed.

A `export GOMAXPROCS=2` might help the program to finish even in the case of an infinite loop, as explained in "[golang: goroute with select doesn't stop unless I added a `fmt.Print()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12712418/6309)".

> `fmt.Print()`  explicitly passes control to some syscall stuff

---

Yes, [go1.2+ has pre-emption in the scheduler](http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption)

> In prior releases, a goroutine that was looping forever could starve out other goroutines on the same thread, a serious problem when `GOMAXPROCS` provided only one user thread.
>
> In Go 1.2, this is partially addressed: The scheduler is invoked occasionally upon entry to a function. This means that any loop that includes **a (non-inlined) function** call can be pre-empted, allowing other goroutines to run on the same thread.

Notice the emphasis (that I put): it is possible that in your example the for loop `atomic.AddUint64(&ops, 1)` is inlined. No pre-emption there.

---

Update 2017: [Go 1.10 will get rid of `GOMAXPROCS`](http://vonc@voncvb:~/.docker$%20more%20config.json%20%20%7B%20%09%22auths%22:%20%7B%20%09%09%22registry.intramundi.com%22:%20%7B%20%09%09%09%22auth%22:%20%22Y2hhZmZpb2w6QUtDcDVaMk5oSngydUNBeDY3YmR5ZmFORGpyRFNQVTVnSExncWZ4NVd0MWhpV1dhaDE2TFNwd3NVV2JEOEdMRjFhYkp0NlhHSw==%22,%20%09%09%09%22email%22:%20%22daniel.chaffiol-ext@amundi.com%22%20%09%09%7D%20%09%7D,%20%09%22HttpHeaders%22:%20%7B%20%09%09%22User-Agent%22:%20%22Docker-Client/17.07.0-ce%20(linux)%22%20%09%7D%20%7D).

Comment: **This** from golang.org: _In prior releases, a goroutine that was looping forever could starve out other goroutines on the same thread, a serious problem when GOMAXPROCS provided only one user thread. In Go 1.2, this is partially addressed: The scheduler is invoked occasionally upon entry to a function. This means that any loop that includes a (non-inlined) function call can be pre-empted, allowing other goroutines to run on the same thread._

Comment: @xged it wouldn't work in playground though, as commented in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20836784/6309

Comment: @xged I have edited the answer: if the for loop is inlined, you won't have any pre-emption.

Comment: @xged probably because GOMAXPROCS is always 1 and, since it doesn't work outside playground (because of inlining), it wouldn't work inside playground.